# Seeing high rate of SocketTimeoutException from calling calendar api

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Our app uses Calendar API extensively and since 10PM PDT on 6/19/2019, we are seeing high rate of SocketTimeoutException from using the Calendar API java client. It's not so bad that our app is entirely broken, but it's bad enough that it's hard to make any sequence of event updates without a failure.

I believe the default timeout is 20 seconds (which I thought was already pretty long) and we up'd it to 30 seconds but did not help. Should the timeout be longer than 30 seconds? for event insert/update/delete calls?

Is it possible that we're being rate limited somehow? (Though I believe that would be returned with 403 exception with relevant error message, not SocketTimeoutException) Or is Google Calendar experiencing some other issues after the outage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're inserting thousands of files simultaneously, it's conceivable that you are choking some resource (sockets, bandwidth, etc).

- You may need to optimize your code by reducing the number of API calls made simultaneously per user/sec.
- Increase the read timeouts: [Timeouts and Errors](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors)

Comment: hmm I don't think our usage is that high.. Also, we're seeing a lot more Connect timed out than read timeouts and our traffic did not increase during that time period at all... thanks for your answer though!